# Divide the contents of a field separated by commas into multiple lines, what's the meaning of these SQL when using XML in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

In SQL Server, I want to divide the contents of a column separated by commas into multiple lines. The example like

```
id         value 
-----------------------
1          aa,bb 
2          aaa,bbb,ccc
```

After dividing the value with id, the results should be like:

```
id        value 
----------------
1          aa 
1          bb 
2          aaa 
2          bbb 
2          ccc
```

The SQL statement I found is this:

```
create table tb(id int, value varchar(30)) 

insert into tb values(1,'aa,bb') 
insert into tb values(2,'aaa,bbb,ccc') 
go 

SELECT A.id, B.value 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         id, [value] = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <v>' + REPLACE([value], ',', ' 
  </v> <v>') + ' </v> </root>') 
     FROM 
         tb) A 
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT 
         value = N.v.value('.', 'varchar(100)') 
     FROM 
         A.[value].nodes('/root/v') N(v) 
    ) B
```

I just want to know what's the detailed meaning of the following statement?

```
  SELECT value = N.v.value('.', 'varchar(100)') 
  FROM A.[value].nodes('/root/v') N(v)
```

what's does the `N.v` infer to? What's the meaning of `N.v.value('.', 'varchar(100)')`, `nodes('/root/v')` and the last `N(v)`?

Answer (score 0):

syntax for node query not [query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type)

**`nodes (XQuery) as Table(Column)`**

As per your query N is alias for table and v is name for column.

Query **value.node(/root/v)** mean "**value**" is XML and the xpath **"/root/v"** values are stored in **"v"** column on table **"N"**.

ie

```
  DECLARE @x xml   
SET @x='<Root>  
    <row id="1"><name>Larry</name><oflw>some text</oflw></row>  
    <row id="2"><name>moe</name></row>  
    <row id="3" />  
</Root>'  
SELECT T.c.query('.') AS result  
FROM   @x.nodes('/Root/row') T(c)  
GO
```

where  T(c) T is alias for table and c is column.